# How to add if statement to exclude specific empty rows

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach

I have a `SELECT` statement which is successfully populating the data I need within the following table. However I want to filter down the results with an if statement. Basically I want to have it where:

If there is a value for `Timestamp` and/or `msg` get results else leave blank.

```
<?php foreach ( $result as $query ){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $query->text1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $query->text2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $query->text3; ?></td>
        <td><?php if($query->Timestamp!=""){echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($query->Timestamp)); }?></td>
        <td><?php echo $query->msg; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
```

How would I write this if statement into this code in order to only show rows that produced either a `date` or a `msg` or both?

As requested I have added the initial query though a bit intricate hence I was hoping to avoid messing with it any further.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT DISTINCT text3,
        CASE WHEN text3 LIKE '%S' THEN S_Msg
             WHEN text3 LIKE '%N' THEN N_Msg
             ELSE E_Msg
             END AS msg,
        CASE WHEN text3 LIKE '%S' THEN S_Time
             WHEN text3 LIKE '%N' THEN N_time
             WHEN text3 LIKE '%E' THEN E_time
             END AS Timestamp,
        value1
        FROM table_1 AS a
        INNER JOIN table_2 AS b
            ON a.Value2 = b.Value3
        WHERE value1='$value1'");
```

I am open to suggestions for either solution that works :)

## UPDATE

I have tried using the suggestion made by M Khalid Junaid

```
 having (msg is not null and msg <> '')
 or (Timestamp is not null and Timestamp <> '')
```

however this causes issues with other queries no longer loading as I think due to me not using groups but multiple different queries on the page and this is just one of them within a bigger set of queries.

I fear this one is over my head. to replicate this on a sqlfiddle i would need to setup 3 database tables so will need a day to prepare that unless someone has another solution. I am still open to the cop out of a if statement as well lol

Comment: It can also be done directly in query, Can you add the select statement in your post ?

Comment: `if(!empty($whatever)){/* show */}`?

Comment: what is `oowd`?  The pro solution will be to handle this in the query, not php.  Show your query (or table structure).

Comment: i have added my query to the question for further insight as per your requests :)

Comment: If you can create a sqlfiddle link for us with some sample data, then we can write and test our offerings for 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

To get the results if any criteria is met you can use following

```
select  distinct text3,
        case when text3 like '%S' then S_Msg when text3 like '%N' then N_Msg else E_Msg end as msg,
        case when text3 like '%S' then S_Time when text3 like '%N' then N_time when text3 like '%E' then E_time end as Timestamp,
        value1 
from table_1 as a 
inner join table_2 as b on a.Value2 = b.Value3 
where value1='$value1'
having (msg is not null and msg <> '')
or (Timestamp is not null and Timestamp <> '')
```

Not sure about how your data is saved in DB as `NULL` or with empty so i added both filters. Purpose to use `having` clause is to apply filter on custom aliases

Comment: let me try this out I will also check into the sqlfiddle site as I only have a jsfiddle acct currently and it seems that may assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an AND statement at the end that checks Timestamp or N_msg as not being empty

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results(
"SELECT DISTINCT text3,
    CASE WHEN text3 like '%S' THEN S_Msg
         WHEN text3 like '%N' THEN N_Msg
         ELSE E_Msg
         END AS msg,
    CASE WHEN text3 LIKE '%S' THEN S_Time
         WHEN text3 LIKE '%N' THEN N_time
         WHEN text3 LIKE '%E' THEN E_time
         END AS Timestamp,
    value1
    FROM table_1 AS a
    INNER JOIN table_2 AS b
        ON a.Value2 = b.Value3
    WHERE value1='$value1'
    AND N_msg != '' OR S_time != '' OR N_time != '' OR E_time != ''");
```

Comment: would I be able to do that for all 3 filter conditions as in for E, S and N in the same query?

Comment: Yes, you definitely can. I've updated my post with a possible solution to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it like this - using the alias in a `having` clause

```
select distinct 
    text3, 
    case 
        when text3 like '%S' then S_Msg 
        when text3 like '%N' then N_Msg 
        else E_Msg 
    end as msg,
    case 
        when text3 like '%S' then S_Time 
        when text3 like '%N' then N_time 
        when text3 like '%E' then E_time 
    end as Timestamp, 
    value1 
    from table_1 as a 
    inner join table_2 as b on a.Value2 = b.Value3 
    having value1='$value1' and msg is not null and timestamp is not null
```